# declaring a global dynamic variable in python

Tags: python

I'm a python/programming newbie and maybe my question has no sense at all.

My problem is that I can't get a variable to be global if it is dynamic, I mean I can do this:

```
def creatingShotInstance():

    import movieClass

    BrokenCristals = movieClass.shot()
    global BrokenCristals #here I declare BrokenCristals like a global variable and it works, I have access to this variable (that is a  shot class instance) from any part of my script.
    BrokenCristals.set_name('BrokenCristals')
    BrokenCristals.set_description('Both characters goes through a big glass\nand break it')
    BrokenCristals.set_length(500)
    Fight._shots.append(BrokenCristals)

def accesingShotInstance():
    import movieClass

    return BrokenCristals.get_name()#it returns me 'BrokenCristals'
```

but if instead of doing that I declare a string variable like this:

```
def creatingShotInstance():

    import movieClass

    a = 'BrokenCristals'

    vars()[a] = movieClass.shot()
    global a #this line is the only line that is not working now, I do not have acces to BrokenCristals class instance from other method, but I do have in the same method.
    eval(a+".set_name('"+a+"')")
    eval(a+".set_description('Both characters goes through a big glass\nand break it')")
    eval(a+".set_length(500)")
    Fight._shots.append(vars()[a])

def accesingShotInstance():
    import movieClass

    return BrokenCristals.get_name()#it returns me 'BrokenCristals is not defined'
```

I tried this :

```
global vars()[a]
```

and this:

```
global eval(a)
```

but It gives me an error. What should I do?

Comment: Take the hint.  Don't do this.  It doesn't make sense in the long run to have a "dynamic" variable.  Why would you even want such a thing?

Comment: aaronasterling is not a joke( thanks for your nice comment anyway) what I'm trying to do is to create a class instance with a name that I get from an entry in an UI, so the name is a dynamic variable.

Comment: Well then Ned Batchelder solveed the problem for you. Unless you want a quasi-fancy metaclass that registers instances based on the name of the movie and provides a constructor implementing the fly-weight pattern. Ned's solution is almost certainly better.

Comment: Remember that `global a` deals with a global variable named 'a'; `global a` becomes `global('a')`, not `global(a)`, if you see what I mean (not that global is a function - `global(a)` won't work).

Comment: If the variable, including its very name are dynamic, how can you be hardcoding it into functions? If you're going to use a global variable for this, give it an unchanging global name and make it a container object of some kind, like a dictionary or class instance, and store any data you need inside of it. BTW, the [docs](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html?highlight=vars#vars) suggest **not** modifying the dictionary `vars()` returns.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Instead of a dynamic global variable, use a dict:

```
movies = {}

a = 'BrokenCristals'

movies[a] = movieClass.shot()
movies[a].set_name(a)
# etc
```

Comment: sorry but I still having the same problem, when I try get values from the BrokenCristals shot class instance from any other method I get this message: name 'BrokenCristals' is not defined....any idea?

Comment: try `movies['BrokenCristals'].get_name()`, for example.  You don't have a variable named BrokenCristals.  You have a dict named `movies` with a key of `'BrokenCristals'`.

Comment: thanks a lot both for the answer and your patience with a newbie like me :-D

Answer (score 19):

For completeness, here's the answer to your original question. But it's almost certainly not what you meant to do -- there are very few cases where modifying the scope's `dict` is the right thing to do.

```
globals()[a] = 'whatever'
```

Comment: sorry it doesn't seem to work...I still getting this message: name 'BrokenCristal, is not defined

Comment: This isn't actually working for me in Python 2.7. It seems to modify the globals, but then when I leave the scope, the globals revert to what they were previously.

Comment: Thank you, it actually works for Python 2.7.17, at least I could pickle and unpickle a namedtuple, which was dynamically created in other module (and I added it to globals there).

Answer (score 2):

The global keyword specifies that a variable you're using in one scope actually belongs to the outer scope.  Since you do not have nested scopes in your example, global doesn't know what you're trying to do.  See [Using global variables in a function other than the one that created them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/423379/global-variables-in-python/423596#423596)

Answer (score 0):

## Your code works fine!

#### It was just a spelling mistake and missing brackets!

First syntax error there are no square brackets:

```
  File "main.py", line 6
    global BrokenCristals
    ^
SyntaxError: name 'BrokenCristals' is assigned to before global declaration
```

Second syntax error there is no letter s on the end of global:

```
  File "main.py", line 6
    global [BrokenCristals]
           ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

#### Corrected syntax:

```
def creatingShotInstance():

    import movieClass

    BrokenCristals = movieClass.shot()
    globals [BrokenCristals]
    BrokenCristals.set_name('BrokenCristals')
    BrokenCristals.set_description('Both characters goes through a big glass\nand break it')
    BrokenCristals.set_length(500)
    Fight._shots.append(BrokenCristals)

def accesingShotInstance():
    import movieClass

    return BrokenCristals.get_name()
```

#### Corrected syntax using declared string:

```
def creatingShotInstance():

    import movieClass

    a = 'BrokenCristals'

    vars()[a] = movieClass.shot()
    globals [a] 
    eval(a+".set_name('"+a+"')")
    eval(a+".set_description('Both characters goes through a big glass\nand break it')")
    eval(a+".set_length(500)")
    Fight._shots.append(vars()[a])

def accesingShotInstance():
    import movieClass

    return BrokenCristals.get_name()
```