# Use iterator as variable name in function python

Tags: python

I saw this question and I would like to know if is possible to use something to solve a problem I have.

I defined list of mathematical object

> obj1,obj2,...,objn

And I have a function `fun` which does something with these objects

```
sol1=fun(obj1)
sol2=fun(obj2)
...
soln=fun(objn)
```

Now what I wanted is use a for loop to calculate all the `sol1`. I know I can do it putting all the object on a list but I was wondering if is possible do something else.

Comment: do you or don't you have all the obj1, obj2, ..., objn in a list?

Comment: I forgot to add a link to this
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8530694/use-iterator-as-variable-name-in-python-loop
I know I can do a it all the object on a list but I was wondering if there is another way to do it. For some reasons could be useful to me have all solutions as sol_i instead sol[i].

Comment: there are multiple ways to do what you're asking for (exec, globals, ...). However, these methods are usually highly frowned upon and using a list or a dict is lot more pythonic

Comment: Hi Julien, the objects are not (meant to be) on a list. I agree that using  a list is more pythonic but as I need the k object to be objk and not obj[k] I'm looking for some possible alternative. This is due to the particular nature of the object obj.
As example if I'm in a multidimensional space I can use x[0] as x_1 and x[n-1] as x_n but if i want to do a partial derivative I much prefer to have my  variable called x_k than x[k-1]. I hope it is more clear. And sorry again to everyone for the bad edited question.

Comment: I don't see why this justifies not using a list ...

Comment: @JulienSpronck: This is a math software written in python:
http://doc.sagemath.org/html/en/prep/Quickstarts/Multivariable-Calculus.html#partial-differentiation
and there is an example with 2 variables only. When you use more than 3 of them you name them x_1,x_2,...,x_n. There is no reasons that justifies using a list for x.
I hope this clarify a little bit.

Answer (score 1):

```
sol_iterator = (fun(x) for x in obj_iterator)
```

Answer (score 1):

> I defined list of mathematical object obj1,obj2,...,objn

So you have

```
objs = [obj1, obj2, obj3]
```

and want to create a list of the results?

The easiest thing is

```
sols = [fun(obj) for obj in objs]
```

Answer (score 0):

So you have:

```
obj1,obj2,...,objn
```

and some function, let us say:

```
def func(obj):
    print(obj*2))
```

So, you are looking for this:

```
for i in range(1,n+1):
   fun(eval("obj"+str(i)))
```

Comment: Thank you, this is partly what I'm looking for. But in this way i don't have sol1,sol2, etc.

Comment: Well this answer gets you most of the way there. Possibly you need to use `exec` rather than eval to create variables with variable names, e.g.
`for i in range(1,n+1): exec('sol{0} = fun(obj{0})'.format(str(i)), globals(), locals())`

Comment: Disclaimer: While the above may work (I didn't test it), whatever you are really trying to achieve, this is not the best way to do it.

Comment: just change the _print_ on the function for a return, and use the `exec` command to asign "sol"+str(index) to each call of the function.
I agree with @skolsuper this is not a good way to to this!

Comment: @skolsuper: you can see the discussion with Julien above. Thanks for your answer it works for fun with one input. But what if I have a fun(obj_i, b) where b is given and not changing over the loop?

Comment: `exec` gets passed your global and local variables, so you can just change the string to `fun(obj{0}, b)`, the interpreter should resolve b with no problem