# Alternatives to using an interator for variable names

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe, for-loop

I am relatively new to Python, coming from a Stata background, and am still struggling with some core Python concepts. For example, i'm currently working on a small program that hits the [US Census Bureau API](https://pypi.org/project/censusgeocode/) to geocode some addresses and my instinct is to loop over my csv files, feed them into the API call, and then name the output(s) sequentially using the iterator. E.g.

```
import censusgeocode
import json
import pandas as pd

cg = censusgeocode.CensusGeocode()
for i in range(1,3):
    k = cg.addressbatch('dta/batchfiles/split_test ' + str(i) + '.csv')
    json_string = json.dumps(k)
    test_{i} = pd.read_json(json_string)
```

I know the `test_{i}` syntax is incorrect and would return an error but the above gives you a sense of what I am trying to do conceptually. However, i've read elsewhere (e.g. in [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8530694/use-iterator-as-variable-name-in-python-loop)) that this is not a good approach in Python. **Can someone advise me on what a better approach would be?** Is it better to simply append all the `k`s together into a massive json file and then transform them in one go? If so, how do I go about doing that?

I have hundreds of csv files that I want to loop over, and after calling the API for each I want to append them all together into a single dataframe -- am not sure if that's useful context but just trying to communicate where I want to get to eventually.

Any help would be very much appreciated!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I create variable variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1373164/how-do-i-create-variable-variables)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You really do not want to pass through json!

`addressbatch` returns a nice list of dicts that can directly be used to smoothly feed a pandas DataFrame.

So you have two ways here: build a large list of dicts and build the dataframe in the end:

```
data = []
for i in range(1,3):
    k = cg.addressbatch('dta/batchfiles/split_test ' + str(i) + '.csv')
    data.extend(k)         # add the new rows to the main list

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

The alternative is to build a dataframe per csv file, store it into a list and concat everything in the end:

```
dfs = []
for i in range(1,3):
    k = cg.addressbatch('dta/batchfiles/split_test ' + str(i) + '.csv')
    dfs.append(pd.DataFrame(k))

df = pd.concat(dfs)
```

Both methods are roughly equivalent. In my tests, the first one seems to be slightly more efficient, but with same magnitude order.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you coud create one main DataFrame and add to it an extra field representing `i`, Then, while looping over your CSV files, you could load the data as a new DataFrame, add the i-field to every line and [append](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.append.html#pandas.DataFrame.append) the read data to your main DataFrame.

p.s. in `k = cg.addressbatch('dta/batchfiles/split_test ' + str(i) + '.csv')`
I would recommend the use os.path.join() for this purpose

Comment: Hi Marco, thanks a lot for this. Can I ask what the benefit of using `os.path.join()` is?

Comment: one advantage is, for example, that if you ran your program on an OS that uses a different separator for path names (e.g. windows vs. linux) it would still work. Also os.path has a set of very useful tools for dealing with paths, it's worth giving it a look :)

Comment: Awesome. Thanks again! I will look into it