# Exec statement won't properly define names

Tags: python, python-2.7

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [declaring a global dynamic variable in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4277056/declaring-a-global-dynamic-variable-in-python)

```
>>> def f():
        global cat
        exec 'cat'+'="meow"'
        return
>>> f()
>>> cat
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#23>", line 1, in <module>
    cat
NameError: name 'cat' is not defined
```

This is just a stripped down example of the issue I've come across. In my actual script, I need various instances of a class be created and named, hence the exec statement.

Just calling

```
exec 'cat'+'="meow"'
```

directly in the shell works fine, but as soon as it's packed in a function, it doesn't seem to work anymore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

looks like the exec ignores the global, the documentation is a bit vague. but this works:

```
>>> def f():
...         global cat
...         exec 'global cat; cat'+'="meow"'
... 
>>> 
>>> f()
>>> cat
'meow'
```

Comment: Excuse me while I run off to write a PEP on replacing the `global` keyword with `global_and_I_really_understand_why_global_is_almost_always_bad`. (and possibly a similar PEP for `exec`.)

Comment: And, by the way, the first `global cat` is completely unnecessary; just the one inside the `exec` is in the scope where the name is used.

Comment: @Wooble yeah I just forgot to delete it copying his example. and bad or not is not the question here. it's a weird pattern but who am I to judge.

Comment: Well, I personally don't downvote for telling people how to do things they shouldn't be doing, but I can certainly see the downvoter's point :)

Comment: Well then, I guess I'll stop answering people who shouldn't be doing what they're doing in my opinion!  ;)

Answer (score 3):

I still don't understand why you are using exec, its a bad design choice and alternatives are usually easier, for example instead of global and then something else you could simply do this

```
ns = {}

def f():
    ns["cat"] = "miow"

print ns
```

Now isn't that cleaner?

Comment: sorry, but this isn't even close to what I intend to do. I want to define a global variable, not a dictionary key.

Comment: Why! Why do you want to define a global variable?

Comment: And more importantly, what do you need that a global dictionary can't do?