# Global dict name in a variable

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to have more dict's in my init.py and I want to set its name in a variable. But it wouldn't detect it as the name.

My Program:

```py
from StackOverflow import *

number = input("Which car do you want:")
car = r"Car"+number
print(car["Color"])
print(car["Brand"])
```

StackOverflow\**init**.py:

```py
Car1 = {
    "Color": "Blue",
    "Brand": "Aston Martin"
}

Car2 = {
    "Color": "Red",
    "Brand": "Volvo"
}
```

I expect that it give the color and brand from the chosen car.
But I get this error:

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/Users/stanw/Documents/Projecten/Stani Bot/Programma's/StackOverflow/Choose Car.py", line 5, in <module>
    print(car["Color"])
TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [declaring a global dynamic variable in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4277056/declaring-a-global-dynamic-variable-in-python)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get value of variable entered from user input?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15168765/how-to-get-value-of-variable-entered-from-user-input)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since Python 3.7, you can use `getattr` on modules.

```
import StackOverflow

number = input('Enter a number')
var_name = f'Car{number}'
if hasattr(StackOverflow, var_name):
    car = getattr(StackOverflow, var_name)
else:
    print('Car not found')
```

Answer (score 1):

approach with global variable only works if the variable is in the current module. To get a value in another module, you can use getattr:

```
import other
print getattr(other, "name_of_variable")
```

> **getattr(object, name[, default])**
>
> Return the value of the named attribute of object. name must be a
>   string. If the string is the name of one of the object’s attributes,
>   the result is the value of that attribute. For example, getattr(x,
>   'foobar') is equivalent to x.foobar. If the named attribute does not
>   exist, default is returned if provided, otherwise AttributeError is
>   raised.

something like :

```
import StackOverflow
number = input("Wich car do you want:")
car = r"Car"+number
print (getattr(StackOverflow, car))
```

A note about the various "eval" solutions: you should be careful with eval, especially if the string you're evaluating comes from a potentially untrusted source -- otherwise, you might end up deleting the entire contents of your disk or something like that if you're given a malicious string.

Answer (score -1):

try to change :

```
car = r"Car"+number
```

to:

```
car = globals()["Car" + number]
```

or:

```
car = eval("Car"+number)
```

Comment: It gives the correct result. But `str(number)` can be replaced with `number` in this instance, since `number` is a string and not an integer

Comment: Did you try your evil `eval` solution?

Comment: What makes it so evil ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1832940/why-is-using-eval-a-bad-practice; essentially, what stops the user from entering something like `1; import os; os.remove('./important.file')`?

Comment: It makes sense! If i understand right, `getattr` its much safer solution to use.